# Customizing a textbox + label + css styles

Tags: css, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a a form variable in a controller:

```
# controller
val addForm = Form(
  tuple("email" -> nonEmptyText, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
)

def add = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.home.add(addForm))
}

# view
@(myForm: Form[(String, String)])

@layouts.main("Registration") {
  @helper.form(action = routes.Registration.create()) {

    @helper.inputText(myForm("email"))
    <!-- ..... -->
  }
}
```

There are a couple of the concerns:

1) It produces the following html:

```
<dl class=" " id="email_field">
  <dt><label for="email">email</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
  </dd>
  <dd class="info">Required</dd>
</dl>
```

Which doesn't look good at all. I want it to look something like this:

```
<label class="my_other_class" for="id_my_id">E-mail</label>
<input class="my_class" id="id_my_id" name="email" type="email">
```

**Plus** the tag for showing the errors, in this case this is `<dd class="info">Required</dd>`

2) It **always** shows "**Required**" on a view, even on the first load. It's even not red, it's a normal text. It want it to be red at least, preferable - to have any other custom style which I can specify manually.

3) Of course, I want to be able to handle its submitting the standard way:

```
def create = Action { request =>
  addForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    failure =>  // ....,
    success => // ....
  )
}
```

So how do I customize it the way I want?

Of course, I saw this http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFormHelpers